# TSQL/MSSQL Select - zero fill integer

Tags: sql, select, zerofill

I have an SQL select statement:

```
select pk from items
```

it returns:

```
1
2
4
29
8
987654
12313232
```

Now my boss wants something like:

```
000001
000002
000004
000029
000008
987654
12313232
```

He definitely want the output to be six digits minimum (which I think nonsense).

I've tried doing something like `'00000' + convert(nvarchar(6),pk)` which works okay only if the `pk` is just one digit. Do you have any idea how to do this? Should I use conditional statement?

Comment: @nik, and if it exceeds? I'll use it in my Windows Forms Report(.rdlc), also I'm using DataSet(.xsd)

Comment: Use "#000000" so the format string will have at least 6 digits, when less will add zero's

Comment: Don't add overhead to sql code if something can be done through reporting services

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Normally this</strike>

```
RIGHT ('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), pk), 6)
```

But as you have values more than 6 digits, try this

```
LTRIM(RIGHT ('    000000' + CONVERT(varchar(10), pk), 10))
```

But you need a CASE to deal with numbers that are 7-9 digits long:.

```
CASE
    WHEN pk >= 1000000 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), pk)
    ELSE RIGHT ('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), pk), 6)
END
```

Comment: How if it's more than 6 digits? Also, cast doesn't work in my query, I'm using 2008.

Comment: I think I really need a conditional statements. Either your first and second answer doesn't work right. Thanks anyway.